# TypeError: 'MyList' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, class, tuples, iterable

I'm trying to get the length of a Class Object, MyList's, personal iterable, self.it. The code for 2 methods are shown below:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if isinstance(args, (list, tuple)):
        self.it = args 
    else:
        self.it = kwargs

def __len__(self):
    print("len")
    return len(self.it)
```

When the code hits `def__len__(self)`, it produces the following error -

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-205-00a18097c81b> in <module>()
      1 # test your implementation of MyList
----> 2 test_list(MyList)

C:\Users\User\Desktop\beaver\Python_5_HW\graders\grader36.pyc in test_list(StdntClass)

C:\Users\User\Desktop\beaver\Python_5_HW\graders\grader36.pyc in test_guantlet(x, y, *args)

TypeError: 'MyList' object is not subscriptable
```

I've searched this error on StackOverflow but I can't figure out what could be going wrong. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: You are not hitting `__len__`. Your traceback doesn't show what *is* hit (there is no source code for the grader available, understandibly), but the exception indicates you are missing a `__getitem__` method.

Comment: oh gotcha, thanks for tip! @MartijnPieters

Comment: @ChristineZhao You'll want to update your question to be a little more pertinent to the error you're getting.

Comment: Also, `*args` will **always** be a tuple. It could be an empty tuple. It will never be a different type.